# How do you animate a model that consists of multiple different objects?

Tags: animation, rigging, groups

I am looking to animate a model that is comprised of multiple objects.

I'm experienced with modeling but I'm totally new to everything animation. I was wondering if anyone could give me the first few steps so I start heading in the right direction. As you can see in the picture, the model consists of 12 different objects.

during the animation they will act as one piece and then disconnect into their individual parts. Some parts will disconnect fully and others will just rotate while still being connected to the main piece. Thanks for the help bros.

(also any YouTube links that you guys think would help would be greatly appreciated)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the child-of constraint for that.

By animating the influence and the location keyframes (especially the visual location) you can achieve what you want.

A real good explanation can be found here: https://youtu.be/ul6dDAOc7zY?si=6sLOiKKNSezOYzBW

Comment: Awesome, thank you!